# Why is it wrong to tie a depencency into a Business Object?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, separation-of-concerns

In general, it has been told to me that dependencies should be injected.  That concerns should be separated.  That control should be inverted.  But why?

For example, what if we use separation of concerns but don't do inversion of control.  Why is it so wrong?  i.e. see code below for discussion..

```php
class BusinessFunctionality
{
    public $motor;
    function doStuff()
    {
        //i.e. at creation time we are not injecting data 
        //into motor.  We create empty motor then set data to it later
        $this->motor = new Motor();

        //motor loads data into itself
        $this->motor->loadMotor(); 
    }
}

class Motor
{
    public $motorData;
    function loadMotor()
    {
        $motorData = new MotorData();

        //MotorData is another class created to 
        //separate concerns of Motor functionality 
        //from database details

        //we load up data acquired by MotorData, into Motor
        $this->motorData = $motorData->loadMotor();
    }
}


class MotorData
{
    function loadMotor()
    {
        //mock Database
        $type = "industrial";//$db->query("SELECT... FROM .. ");
        return $type;
    }
}

//invocation
$business = new BusinessFunctionality();
$business->doStuff();
print "Motor type is " . $business->motor->motorData;
```

**Question:** What are the problems that will make the approach above prone to issues?

**DataMapper Pattern**

For comparison purposes, a more advocated way ios if I use dependency injection and inversion of control and separation of concerns, I have implemented a `DataMapper` pattern to look something like this:

```
//business object
class MyMotor
{
    private $data;

    function __construct(MotorDataType $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    function getType()
    {
        return $this->data->getType();
    }

}

//data mapper object
class MyMotorMapper
{
    function getMotorWithData()
    {
        //get data. i.e from whatever source
        $data = (new DatabaseMock())->getData();

        //inject data into the object
        $motor = new MyMotor($data);

        //return motor to the caller
        return $motor;
    }
}

class MotorDataType
{
    private $motorType;

    function getType()
    {
        return $this->motorType;            
    }

    function setMotorType($type)
    {
        $this->motorType = $type;
    }
}


//database object
class DatabaseMock
{
    function getData()
    {
        $data = new MotorDataType();
        $data->setMotorType("industrial");
        return $data;
    }
}

//invocation
$motor = (new MyMotorMapper())->getMotorWithData();    
print "Motor type is " . $motor->getType();
```

Not entirely sure I like the way it turned out, but it demonstrates the principles I am trying to show (DI, SOC, IofC)

Comment: Read the book "Clean Code". The answer to this question can probably not be shorter than at least half of this volume, and even then, it is more of a discussion than a "correct answer"

Comment: My guess is that the answer is simple.  The rest is probably setting up a framework of thinking about code, and also accumulated experience of things working better that way